# How to find in MongoDB by last 4 chars in ObjectID?

Tags: mongodb

I don't want to expose the full object ID to the client, instead I want to show him only a short of the last 4 chars of the actual object ID of an entity in the collection.

For example: `ObjectId("5fcca5d997239a74da0d67a9")` will become just `67a9`

So it will be much easier to "talk" with ids of documents instead of the full object it.

Then I need to find the document in the DB using only the 67a9.

Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1146) issue in Jira the resolution is "Won't fix".

`ObjectId` is not a String, is another object, so [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) is no possible.

Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2tanyRYrAW9) example where `$regex` works ok when `_id` is an String but not an `ObjectId`.

So one possible option is duplicate every field `_id` in another field called `id` or whatever where the id is in String format.

Then, you can do this query:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "_id": {
    "$regex": "67a9$"
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KPqFPqbaCSS) where I've added more `_id` fields that not match the pattern

Comment: You can use [ObjectId.toString()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/#ObjectId.toString) to convert an `ObjectId` into a string.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, regex won't work on an ObjectId. But there is an easy workaround. Just use aggregation to first convert your ObjectId into a string and then match it.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      tempId: { $toString: '$_id' },
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      tempId: { $regex: "67a9"}
    }
  }
])
```

Obviously not a great solution to use on very large collections.